# Firebase query supporting transactions

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I asked a question earlier that wasn't completely clear. Below is some code for connecting to a Firebase DB in an Android app;

```
public void updateDBMatches(final String fieldUpd, final Object valueUpd) {
    String getArgument = getArguments().getString("matchid");
    final DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Matches").child("Match_01");

    //final DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Matches").orderByChild("gameID").equalTo(getArgument);;

    ref.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            updates.put(fieldUpd, valueUpd);
            ref.updateChildren(updates);
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }
    });
}
```

The commented out line (final DatabaseReference.... ) is what I want to achieve, but I can't pass in a query (it breaks at the equalTo). If I re-write the code to reference a DB connection passed to a query object I lose the ability to put the update in a transaction block (.runTransaction).

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can't run a transaction against a Query object, which could refer to an unknown set of locations.  Notice that the API docs for [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query) does not show a method called runTransaction to call.

If you want to perform a transaction, you can only do that with a [DatabaseReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference) object, which refers to a single known location in the database.  That's the only way a transaction can operate.  Notice that it has a [runTransaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#runTransaction(com.google.firebase.database.Transaction.Handler)) method.

Please read more about [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).

Comment: Thanks. Seems like a big limitation, as sql dbs can have a transaction irrelevant of the query, makes me wonder about the suitability of high transactional solutions that have non-simple DB structures. I'll have to find a work around.

Comment: Consider Firestore instead.

Comment: Since your update doesn't seem to require the current value of the node it's updating, it doesn't require a transaction. It can just be a regular [multi-location update](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html). But all the same, neither the Firebase Realtime Database nor Cloud Firestore support so-called update queries where you pass the conditions and updates to the server in a single call. Updates are run from a client and require that the client knows the location/key of each item it wants to update.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen With Firestore, you could query for documents, then perform a transaction that involves those each of documents in an atomic update.  There is just the risk that the set of documents you're interested in could change between the query and the beginning of the transaction.